# Facebook Access Token Missing

Tags: facebook

Following instructions to acquire FB access token for desktop app using the manual Login workflow is not producing an access token for the default successful login.

If I add the "user_likes" permission (I'm sure some other permissions would work as well, but "email", "publish_actions" and "public_profile" don't) to the login URL scope argument (thereby engaging the user's agreement to provide that permission), I receive an access token.

E.g.:

This URL -

> https: //www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=https: //www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token

Produces the following response URL -

> https: //www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html
>   *<--NOTE the missing access token*

If I modify the request URL to include "user_likes" as follows -

> https: //www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=https: //www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&response_type=token&scope=user_likes

Produces the expected result URL -

> https: //www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=REDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTEDREDACTED&expires_in=5108029

What am I missing?

I'm using the WPF WebBrowser control on Windows XP (yes, if you can believe that), if that helps?

Comment: If you define scope with pubic_profile you don't get the result ?

Comment: No - tried that in various combinations: by itself, with other permissions, etc.  Only when I add in "user_likes" and I have to acknowledge permission on the second view in the login workflow will it return a token.  There may be other permissions like "user_likes" that will work, but I haven't tested them.  The docs all indicate that it should return a token, with or without additional permissions, but that's not what I am seeing.

Comment: Same problem here. When I wasn't specifying any response_type (defaults to code), the login flow was working, now that I put response_type=token, nothing is returned along with the redirect uri. It works fine on Windows 7/8/8.1 though. Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the origin of the problem. It seems to be an old bug in the WPF WebBrowser control, which [strips out the URL fragment](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ffdf22f8-0df4-4ce4-bdee-632e4cbb5fbb/wpf-webbrowser-control-stripping-out-url-fragment?forum=wpf) used by Facebook to return the access token.

The workaround proposed by Linda Liu, from the Microsoft Customer Support Service, consists in using the WinForms control instead of the WPF one.

Another approach would be to specify response_type=code (response in the query string) instead of response_type=token (response in the URL fragment). The downside: you have to include your app secret in the request (to exchange the code for an access token), which shouldn't be done in the client-side to avoid exposing it. For more details, take a look at [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3#confirm).

Note: I also tried to install the latest hotfixes from Windows Update (target .NET Framework 4.0 on Windows XP) but the problem persisted.